# How to use Chrome developer tools to profile mounting times of React.native components?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, logging, react-native

The chrome development tools provide me with a flame chart showing the execution times of the various methods that are being called as part of the rendering of my react.native iOS application. Although this chart displays many *mountComponent* calls, it does not show which particular component is being rendered. Is there a way to attach this information to the chart?

This is what I see:

[image: many mountComponent calls]

One thing I thought of is logging the parameters together with the function calls. That would give me enough information to see which components take the most time. Is there a way to do this?